# Grails matching dates

Tags: date, grails, criteria

I have a string which is:

```
"may 2013"
```

This refers to the second of May. I am trying to get all instances of PostOrder where the date is the second of May.

What I have tried so far:

```
def t = new Date(new Integer(sp[1]), new Integer(month), 01)
def results = PostOrder.createCriteria().list() {
     ilike('dateCreated', t  )
}
```

Please note I have split the string so sp[1] is 2013 and I have parsed the May so the month variable is not 05.

The above attempt does not work.

The only way I know will work is grabbing all objects and doing a for each on them. parsing the dateCreated to a string then doing a .contains(). But this will get very slow and messy.

Comment: ilike in a date? How about between 1 and 31?

Comment: sorry i should have said dateCreated is of type Date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First point. According to the [documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/createCriteria.html), `ilike()` is a case-insensitive 'like' expression - see [SQL LIKE Operator](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp). So, it cannot accept a date. What you need is just `eq()`.

```
def t = new Date(new Integer(sp[1]), new Integer(month), 1)
def results = PostOrder.createCriteria().list() {
    eq('dateCreated', t)
}
```

Another point. The constructor `Date()` [accepts](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#Date%28int,%20int,%20int%29) the year minus 1900 as the first argument. So, you probably need to subtract `1900` from `new Integer(sp[1])`.
Also, that constructor is deprecated; I would suggest to use `GregorianCalendar(new Integer(sp[1]), new Integer(month), 1).time`.